# ffmpeg задать срок жизни видеофрагменту

Tags: asp.net-core, ffmpeg

Дано:

- Приложение ASP .NET Core.
- Фронтенд на react
- Контроллер на `c#`.
- Есть `rtsp` поток с камеры и `ffmpeg` скрипт, который преобразует его в `hls` (создаёт плейлист `.m3u8` и нарезает сегменты `.ts`). Другой скрипт на `js` чистит папку от сегментов старше 'n' секунд.

Пытаюсь переписать оба скрипта (заводились в окнах терминала) в виде методов контроллера.

Вопрос:

Можно ли совместить два скрипта в одном - задать в `ffmpeg-скрипте` срок жизни создаваемым сегментам?

Comment: В ffmpeg есть опция `-hls_flags delete_segments` специально для удаления старых сегментов https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2

Comment: Не понимаю как сделать ваш ответ принятым (т.е. РЕШЕНИЕМ). Но это именно оно, спасибо!